# Arduino SD Fat Library OpenNext error

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm using the Arduino SD fat library to find a file on an SD card. I'm sending my function a pointer to a `char` array and an object `SdFile` As a template, I based my code on the following example:

```
const uint8_t SD_CS_PIN = 10;

SdFat sd;
SdFile file;
SdFile dirFile;

// Number of files found.
uint16_t n = 0;

// Max of ten files since files are selected with a single digit.
const uint16_t nMax = 10;

// Position of file's directory entry.
uint16_t dirIndex[nMax];

// List files in root directory.
while (file.openNext(&dirFile, O_READ)) 
{
  // Skip directories and hidden files.
  if (!file.isSubDir() && !file.isHidden())
  {
    // Save dirIndex of file in directory.
    dirIndex[n] = file.dirIndex();
    // Print the file number and name.
    Serial.print(n++);
    Serial.write(' ');
    file.printName(&Serial);
    Serial.println();
  }
  file.close();
}
```

---

Below is the code I wrote which is not returning true when `loc.openNext(&dir, O_READ)` with some explanation of my logic.

## Begin

Function echos user input

```
bool FindFile (SdFile dir, char *findname)
{
  Serial.println("getting file");
  const char *p;
  p = findname;
  while (*p) 
  {
    Serial.print(*p);
    p++;
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  bool found = false;
```

## Checks to see if the file name is in the root directory

(this part works)

```
  if(dir.exists(findname))
  {
    ActiveDir=dir;
    found = true;
    Serial.println("found");
  }
```

## Search Recursively

if `findname` is not in `dir`, look for the first subdirectory, check there and continue until found or all subdirectories are checked. the function also skips anything hidden as I don't want the user to be able to choose a hidden file.

```
  else
  {
    //debug marker
    Serial.println("else");
    SdFile loc;
    while (loc.openNext(&dir, O_READ))
    {
      //while loop is always returning false so this part is not running when it should
      //debug marker
      Serial.println("while");
      if (loc.isHidden())
      {
      //file hidden, skip
      }
      else if (loc.isSubDir())
      {
        Serial.println("SUB");
        loc.open(&dir, loc.dirIndex(), O_READ);
        if(FindFile(loc, findname))
        {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    loc.close();
  }
return found;
}
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how `file.openNext(&dirFile, O_READ)` is different from `loc.openNext(&dir, O_READ)`

Edit: updated code to show more of the example code.

Comment: Where is `dirIndex[n] = file.dirIndex();` `dirIndex` defined.  If this is on an Arduino are you aware of the RAM limitations?  Not to mention the potential problems in using recursion on devices with severe memory (e.g. stack) limitations.

Comment: `dirIndex[n]` was defined above in the setup, updated post to reflect. I'm using an Arduino Mega with a fairly limited number of files (I can't see going any farther than 3-5 files deep), so that should alleviate some of the issues with the recursion. If there's a better way to do it, I'd be interested in learning.

Comment: `dirIndex()` is defined in the SD Fat library as returning The index of this file in it's directory